# I can't draw a square when converting a CMYK image to PDF

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagick, cmyk

I can draw a square when I convert an RGB colour image to pdf, but It does not work when I do it with a CMYK image.

Below is my code:

```
    $folderName = "storage\new.pdf");
    $safeArea = new \ImagickDraw();
    $safeArea->setStrokeWidth(2);
    if ($metaData['colourMode'] == 'CMYK') {
        $colorSpace = \imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK;
        $color = "cmyk(0,100,100,0)";
    } else {
        $colorSpace = \imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB;
        $color = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    }
    $safeArea->setStrokeColor($color);
    $safeArea->setFillColor($color);
    $safeArea->setStrokeOpacity(1);
    $safeArea->setFillOpacity(1);
    $safeArea->line(3, 4, $metaData['px_width'] - 4, 3);
    $safeArea->line(3, $metaData['px_height'] - 4, $metaData['px_width'] - 4, $metaData['px_height'] - 3);
    $safeArea->line(3, 4, 4, $metaData['px_height'] - 3);
    $safeArea->line($metaData['px_width'] - 3, 4, $metaData['px_width'] - 4, $metaData['px_height'] - 3);

    $pdf = new \Imagick($path);
    $pdf->setImageResolution($metaData['dpi'], $metaData['dpi']);

    $pdf->transformImageColorspace($colorSpace);
    $pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
    $pdf->drawImage($safeArea);
    $pdf->writeImage(storage_path($folderName));
```

$metaData is and array with all the info of the image, and $path is the path to the image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "It does not work" - It stays at home playing Xbox and eating Doritos?

Comment: Is there a workaround to create a border around the image?  I need one border with a stroke of 2 pixels and colour Red 3 px from the edge of the image and a second one 6 px from the edge of image od colour Blue. @Danack

Comment: I don't think `cmyk(...)` is a valid color function. Try `#00FFFF00`.

Comment: Still does not work @emcconville

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution:

```
    $width = $metaData['orientation'] == 'Landscape' ? $product->bleed_width : (integer) $product->bleed_height;
    $height = $metaData['orientation'] == 'Landscape' ? (integer) $product->bleed_height : $product->bleed_width;

    $canvasHeight = $this->convertMmToPx($height, $metaData['dpi']);
    $canvasWidth = $this->convertMmToPx($width, $metaData['dpi']);

    $canvas = new \Imagick();
    $canvas->newImage($canvasWidth, $canvasHeight, new \ImagickPixel('none'));
    $canvas->setImageResolution($metaData['dpi'], $metaData['dpi']);
    $canvas->transformimagecolorspace(\imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);

    //create png
    $png = new \Imagick();
    $png->newImage($canvasWidth - $this->convertMmToPx(6.1, $metaData['dpi']), $canvasHeight - $this->convertMmToPx(6.1, $metaData['dpi']), new \ImagickPixel('none'));

    $borderWidth = $this->convertMmToPx(0.1, $metaData['dpi']);
    $borderColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
    $imageWidth = $png->getImageWidth();
    $imageHeight = $png->getImageHeight();
    $border = new \ImagickDraw();
    $border->setFillColor('none');
    $border->setStrokeColor(new \ImagickPixel($borderColor));
    $border->setStrokeWidth($borderWidth);
    $border->setStrokeAntialias(false);
    $border->rectangle(
            0, 0, $imageWidth - $this->convertMmToPx(0.1, $metaData['dpi']), $imageHeight - $this->convertMmToPx(0.1, $metaData['dpi'])
    );

    $png->drawImage($border);
    $png->setImageFormat('png');
    $png->setImageResolution($metaData['dpi'], $metaData['dpi']);
    $png->transformimagecolorspace(\imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);

    $canvas->compositeImage(
            $png, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, (($canvasWidth - $png->getImageWidth()) / 2), (($canvasHeight - $png->getImageHeight()) / 2)
    );

    $canvas->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
    $canvas->setImageFormat('pdf');
    $canvas->transformimagecolorspace(\imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
    $canvas->writeImage($filePath);
```